# Installing Aerospike on Ubuntu: not able to start server

Tags: server, aerospike

I have been following these instructions: https://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/install/linux/ubuntu
I have successfully run the following commands:

```
wget -O aerospike.tgz 'https://www.aerospike.com/download/server/latest/artifact/ubuntu16'
tar -xvf aerospike.tgz
cd aerospike-server-community-4.2.0.3-ubuntu16.04/
sudo ./asinstall
```

/opt/aeropspike directory is created as I can see.

but the following directories were not created:

1) /etc/init.d/aerospike
2) /var/log/aerospike

Now I am not able to proceed to step 4 to start Aerospike.

Is there any step that I am missing here, or any other way to view logs and start Aerospike on this machine?

My Machine details:
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start ubuntu server with

**sudo service aerospike start**

it's mentioned above overview in list of all commands

Comment: Thanks that worked! Can you share where exactly you got that command above? I cnt seem to find this list of cmds....

Comment: Also any idea where I can see the logs and system health?

Comment: @user3868051 location of /var/log/aerospike/aerospike.log

Comment: and about command to start aerospike it's there in first window https://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/install/linux/ubuntu

Answer (score 4):

systemd has replaced upstart in Ubuntu 16, so it's `journalctl -u aerospike` for logs.

You also won't find an init.d script as it's been replaced by `/usr/lib/systemd/system/aerospike.service`. Again, because it's now systemd.

Comment: Thanks @Richard Is there any clear documentation for these changes that I can refer to? That would be of great help!

Comment: There's a specific [systemd page](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/manage/aerospike/systemd).   

The link in the yellow overview call-out from the [ubuntu installation page](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/install/linux/ubuntu) is broken for the moment.